# how can I connect to remote desktop of a fedora machine from another linux?

Tags: ssh, remote-desktop, remote-access, fedora-17, xforwarding

I try to connect remote desktop to my fedora machine from another linux machine. I did it for specific programs and run them with GUI however I cannot find a way to remote desktop access other then teamviewer. Is is also possible to use ssh to see the remote machine desktop or is there an other method around ? I am running Fedora 17 on host and I aim to connect to it from any other linux distributions.

Comment: Have you tried vnc? google for 'vnc fedora' for how tos

Comment: I did not know vnc but now I know so will search ... thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use vino.

```
Vino is a VNC (Virtual Network Computing) server allowing remote connection 
to your actual desktop.
```

Try this tutorial [Remote Access to the Fedora Linux Desktop](http://www.techotopia.com/index.php/Remote_Access_to_the_Fedora_Linux_Desktop)

good luck